# anaconda package mesa ImportError

Tags: python, anaconda, importerror

I have installed anaconda 4 and created environment with all packages packages that Continuum includes in its default Anaconda installer.

```
conda create -n env_full python=3 anaconda=4
(env_full)neeraj@nicetomeetyou:~$ which anaconda
/home/neeraj/.conda/envs/env_full/bin/anaconda
```

I have installed a package "mesa". To check if it works properly, I wrote the following test file "1.py".

```
import mesa
print('mesa is installed')
```

When I run the file using python in the environment of the anaconda, it shows the ImportError. However, when I check if mesa is installed, it shows that version 10.5.4 is installed as follows:

```
(env_full)neeraj@nicetomeetyou:~$ conda list -f mesa --show
# packages in environment at /home/neeraj/.conda/envs/env_full:
#
mesa                      10.5.4                        0    defaults
(env_full)neeraj@nicetomeetyou:~$ python3 1.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "1.py", line 1, in <module>
import mesa
ImportError: No module named 'mesa'
```

Run using python

```
(env_full)neeraj@nicetomeetyou:~$ python 1.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "1.py", line 1, in <module>
import mesa
ImportError: No module named 'mesa'
```

How do I resolve the problem ?

Following action worked. I created another environment for mesa as 'env_mesa'

```
(env_full)neeraj@nicetomeetyou:~$ source activate env_mesa
```

and then run using python.

```
(env_full)neeraj@nicetomeetyou:~$ source activate env_mesa
discarding /home/neeraj/.conda/envs/env_full/bin from PATH
prepending /home/neeraj/.conda/envs/env_mesa/bin to PATH
(env_mesa)neeraj@nicetomeetyou:~$ python 1.py 
mesa is installed
```

What is the thing that is different in two cases ? even outputs for conda list are same for both the cases

```
(env_mesa)neeraj@nicetomeetyou:~$ conda list -f mesa --show
# packages in environment at /home/neeraj/.conda/envs/env_mesa:
#
mesa                      10.5.4                        0    defaults
(env_full)neeraj@nicetomeetyou:~$ conda list -f mesa --show
# packages in environment at /home/neeraj/.conda/envs/env_full:
#
mesa                      10.5.4                        0    defaults
```

Comment: try `python 1.py `

Comment: tried but did not work, updated the question. Thank you.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the conda mesa package just contains libraries (from the mesa3d project I guess), but no python files. Where did you get the idea that `import mesa` should work? Are you following some kind of example?

Comment: mesa3d is different, mesa is related to agent-based modelling.
The example I want to follow is here: https://github.com/projectmesa/mesa-examples/blob/master/examples/Schelling/Schelling.py

Comment: Well, from the version 10.5.4 in your output, that mesa package is definitely mesa3d and not the one you want to use. Perhaps that doesn't even have a conda package readily available, but you should be able to use `pip` to install it. If I execute `pip install mesa`, then this seems to do the trick. Calling `conda list` afterwards then shows that `Mesa 0.7.5` is installed, and `import mesa` does work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I fixed it using pip instead:

```
pip install mesa
```